# Removing part of DirectoryName

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove part of a path in a string but it doesn't actually remove anything. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this method.

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/FastDL-Generator-Input/";
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path + "materials/");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{                
    string filePath = file.DirectoryName.Replace(path, "");
    status3.Text = filePath;
}
```

It doesn't run with any errors, but it's not removing anything. This is the output

```
"C:\Users\*****\source\repos\FastDL Generator\FastDL Generator\bin\Debug\FastDL-Generator-Input\materials\test"
```

It should be printing

```
"materials\test"
```

instead. If you can provide any advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You really should use `Path.Combine` when you want to combine paths together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a forward slash in your path, I ran your code on my machine using back slash and it worked as you expected.

Try this:

```
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "FastDL-Generator-Input\\";
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path + "materials\\");
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        string filePath = file.DirectoryName.Replace(path, "");
        status3.Text = filePath;
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively using `Patch.Combine` would work and you don't even need to specify the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these two lines:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/FastDL-Generator-Input/";
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path + "materials/");
```

To this:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "FastDL-Generator-Input\\";
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path + "materials\\");
```

Note the change in direction of the slashes in the path.